# Get data without (HABTM) associated data

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a HABTM relation that works well, when I do a `find()` on `Foo` I get something like this:

```
{
    "Foo": {
        "ID": "32",
        ...
    },
    "Bar": [
        {
            "ID": "3",
             ...
        },
        {
            "ID": "4",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

...but in some cases I only want to get `Foo` without the related `Bars` (not even querying for `Bars`). How can I do this?

I've tried:

```
$this->{$this->modelClass}->find('all', array('fields' => array($this->modelClass.'.*')));
```

...but it doesn't help.

In case it matters, my Models are:

```
class Foo extends AppModel {
    public $primaryKey = "ID";

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
            'Bar' =>
            array(
                    'className' => 'Bar',
                    'joinTable' => 'bars_foos',
                    'foreignKey' => 'foo_ID',
                    'associationForeignKey' => 'bar_ID'
            )
    );
}
class Bar extends AppModel {
    public $primaryKey = "ID";

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Foo' =>
            array(
                'className' => 'Foo',
                'joinTable' => 'bars_foos',
                'foreignKey' => 'bar_ID',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'foo_ID'
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I found this in the Model Attributes documentation:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive

In my case, `Model->find('all', array('recursive' => -1))` is doing what I want.